# How to add two column with default value to the existing table in hive?

Tags: pyspark, hive, hiveql

Employee table having many records and how to add two more columns(load_year,load_month) with default values like load_year=2019 and load_month=7 for all the records?

Comment: If you're using Hive and HiveQL, I recommend checking out the [Hive Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+dml). The admins are pretty good at keeping the docs up to date - I probably accounted for a good portion of their traffic when I used Hive regularly, haha.

Answer (score 0):

use `AlTER TABLE` IN hive:

```
ALTER TABLE name ADD COLUMNS (col_spec[, col_spec ...]);
```